# Rails HTML escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in a Rails 3.2.1 helper that keeps escaping HTML even if i don't want it, and i can't figure out how to turn off the html escaping on this method (calling raw or html_safe doesn't work):

```
module OffersHelper
  def price_tag(amount)
    amount = amount.to_f
    floor = amount.floor
    cents = ((amount - amount.floor) * 100).to_i
    content_tag(:h2) do
      html = floor.to_s
      html << content_tag(:sup, cents) if cents > 0
      html
    end
  end
end
```

If i remove the nested content_tag (the sup tag), the html escaping is turned off...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how're you're calling `raw`/`html_safe`? And how you're rendering the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
module OffersHelper
  def price_tag(amount)
    amount = amount.to_f
    floor = amount.floor
    cents = ((amount - amount.floor) * 100).to_i
    out = content_tag(:h2) do
      html = floor.to_s
      html << content_tag(:sup, cents) if cents > 0
      html
    end
    out.html_safe
  end
end
```